# IDE freezes up when running VBA in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Whenever I run any VBA code in Access 2016 the IDE freezes up after a few seconds and shows (Not Responding) in the title bar. The code still runs (although seems to be quite slow) and the immediate window does not update with any debug.print messages until the code is interrupted or finished at which time all of the debug.print messages appear.

This has been happening ever since we upgraded from Access 2010 to 2016. I have tried googling to find what is causing this but haven't been able to find a solution. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If it's happening on any database then it sounds like a corrupt install. I would do a repair or even a full re-install.

Comment: Hi Minty. Thanks for the reply. We have a number of PCs with Access installed locally and it is happening on all of them. Do you think it is unlikely that they are all corrupt?

Comment: Did you also upgrade to Windows 10 along the way? Anyway, the workaround is to put `DoEvents` calls inside long running code (e.g. in loops).

Comment: 1. Check Linked table manager and see if all sources are valid  2. Use Analyse Performance option

Comment: No, we are still running Windows 7 Enterprise. I'll try the DoEvents workaround. I'm still hoping to fix the root cause of the issue as it seems to be running a bit slower as well. If I reopen in 2010 this doesn't happen